# KDB/Q query for rows matching criteria per month

Tags: kdb

I would like to perform a query in Q/KDB that retrieves rows the fulfills the following criteria.

1. Rows with the same name in a month must only have completed marked.
2. Names should be distinct i.e. if they fulfill condition 1, they should only appear as a singular entry.

**Initial Table:**

```
completed name month
--------------------
yes       x    1    
no        x    1    
yes       y    2
yes       y    2    
no        a    3    
yes       a    4    
yes       b    4    
no        b    4    
no        b    4  
yes       y    5
```

**Initial Table Divvied Up by Months**

```
completed name month
--------------------
yes       x    1    
no        x    1
---------------------    
yes       y    2
yes       y    2    
--------------------
no        a    3    
--------------------
yes       a    4    
yes       b    4    
no        b    4    
no        b    4  
--------------------
yes       y    5
```

**Resultant Table:**

```
completed name month
--------------------
yes       y    2    
yes       a    4 
yes       y    5
```

**Explanation:**

1. In month **1**, only **x** transacted but has not completed one deal, hence it is not in our final table.
2. In month **2**, only **y** transacted with both deals being completed, hence it is in our final table.
3. In month **3**, only **a** transacted but the deal is not completed.
4. In month **4**, both **a** and **b** transacted, but since **b** has uncompleted deals, it is left out.
5. In month **5**, only **y** transacted, so it is added to the final table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Carrein you can use the following using the each right adverb and the fby filter

```
distinct select from tab where ({all`yes=/:x};completed)fby([]name;month)
```

Additionally you might want to make use of a Boolean vector for the completed column for simplicity

Comment: ```e.g:

table:flip `completed`name`month!(1011011001b;`x`x`y`y`a`a`b`b`b`y;1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5); ```

```distinct select from table where (all;completed) fby([]name;month)```

Comment: No need for each-right adverb. `{all \`yes=x}` is sufficient. `=` is a vector function.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to modify the given query to permit a number of cancelled deals i.e. 5 per month but still must have a minimum of 1 complete per month.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most q-ist answer, but at least it works:

```
t: ([]completed:`yes`no`yes`yes`no`yes`yes`no`no`yes; name:`x`x`y`y`a`a`b`b`b`y;month:1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5)

(cols t) xcols `month xasc ungroup {select from x where all each completed = `yes} select distinct completed by name,month from t

completed name month
--------------------
yes       y    2    
yes       a    4    
yes       y    5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use DolphinDB instead of kdb+, the solution would be more readable.

```
tbl = table(1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 as completed, `x`x`y`y`a`a`b`b`b`y as name, 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 as month)
select top 1 * from tbl context by month, name having min(completed)=1

completed name month
--------- ---- -----
1         y    2
1         a    4
1         y    5
```

The clause `context by` in the sql statement is similar to `group by`. But it doesn't require all columns in `select` clause be aggregated values. Also, it can work together with `having` clause to filter groups. The `top n` clause applies to each group.